# Data from getBoundingClientRect is not correct after calling setZoomFactor in Electron

Tags: reactjs, electron

I'm using Electron and trying to zoom in a page using

```
this.webview.setZoomFactor(zoomFactor);
```

after that, I am trying to get the elements from the page

```
const elements = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  const element = elements[i].getBoundingClientRect();
}
```

but the elements do not seem to care about the zooming and their data is not correct. Any idea why this is happening, and how can I fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Chromium "bug" that won't be fixed. See [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=429140).

The suggested workaround is to do your own conversion:

> When you create separate coordinate spaces using zoom on sub elements on the page you should be responsible as the developer for managing the conversion of measurements between them.